# client side validation is not working for DropDownListFor in razor MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When I click the button client side validation is not working below is my view and model

view:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


 @using (Html.BeginForm("Guestlogin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                for (int i =0; i <1; i++)
                {
             @Html.DropDownListFor(per => per.[i].Gender, new[] {
                                            new SelectListItem(){Text = "Male" , Value="Male"},
                                            new SelectListItem(){Text ="Female" , Value = "Female"},
                                        }, "Select Your Gender")@Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o[i].Gender)
            }

            <button type="submit" name="Button"/>
            }
```

model:

```
[Required]
public string Gender { set;get;}
```

Comment: have you defined data annotations ? show that in question

Comment: Have you referenced the jquery.validate.* javascripts?

Comment: yeah I have  refered the jquery

Comment: can u show some jquery code of yours so we can provide more help

Comment: what does "not working" mean? if you mean it passes validation when it's not supposed to check to see if the value of your default item is `""` and not `"Select Your Gender"` when rendered

Comment: the validation is perfectly firing when i remove forloop

Comment: oh lol.. iguess i see whats going on try using IEnumerable<Gender>

Comment: I have removed the "Select Your Gender" and tried with "" then also client side message not firing.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer: how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

check ur model:

```
public class urvalidationmodel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public IEnumerable<Gender> gender { get; set; }
}
```

js :

```
function Gender(sender, args) {
    var v = document.getElementById('Gender').value;
    if (v == 'Male' || v == 'Female') {
        args.IsValid = true; // Valid
    }
    else {
        args.IsValid = false; // Invalid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple just at this code in your view before the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Guestlogin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            for (int i =0; i <1; i++)
```

Before that Add this below code:

```
   @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Guestlogin", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            for (int i =0; i <1; i++)
```